How to calculate the ratio of the Gamma-function and its derivative $\frac{ \Gamma'(x) }{ (\Gamma (x))^2 }$ around their poles
I stumbled across the the ratio $ \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{ \Gamma'(x) }{ (\Gamma (x))^2 }$.
$\Gamma$ is the Gamma
-function $\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty dt \ e^{-t} \ t^{x-1}$ and it's derivative $\Gamma'(x) = \int_0^\infty dt \ e^{-t} \ t^{x-1} \ \ln t$. Wolfram Alpha says the limit is equal to -1, but I do not know how to verify the result.
I was wondering if one could apply the rule of L'Hospital, as the numerator and denominator each show a pole at x=0. Just applying this rule hardly helps me, as the numerator and denominator still contain integrals and for now I see no reason how multiple applications should work in a better way.
Can you sketch how to calculate the limit?

The key is the functional equation $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$. Thus $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ \Gamma'(x) }{ (\Gamma (x))^2 }=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ x^2\Gamma'(x) }{ (\Gamma (x+1))^2 }=\lim_{x \to 0} x^2\Gamma'(x)$. Now we can expand $\Gamma'(x)$ near $x=0$ to obtain the limit as $-1$.

Thank you Efe, this helps. Why didn't you submit it as an answer?
